# "Скучаю по вас" или "Скучаю по вам"?

Tags: падежи, местоимения

Я человек, так сказать, не близкий к филологии. Давно интересует вопрос: как правильно: "Скучаю по вас" или "Скучаю по вам"?

Comment: Это вы из ЖЖ пришли? https://bakluzhino.livejournal.com/157331.html :-DDD

Answer (score 6):

Традиционно правильно **по вас**, но в современном языке есть тенденция к замене предложного дательным, и эта двойная норма отражена в словарях.

Развёрнутые ответы даны в теме 
[**Скучаю: по вам, по вас или за вас?**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/436491/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81)

Лично я предпочитаю традиционный вариант, в том числе для существительных.

> Что же приводит к изменению управления? Это очень непростой вопрос и
>   на него не всегда легко ответить, однако некоторые причины изменений
>   установить всё-таки можно. Разберём в качестве примера глагол **скучать**.
>   В XIX веке этот глагол имел 4 значения (и соответственно 4 типа
>   управления). Рассмотрим эти значения (значения и примеры приводятся по
>   «Словарю языка Пушкина»):
>
> **№ п/п**     
>   **Значение**                
>   **Управление**             
>   **Примеры**
>
> **1**            испытывать скуку    без
>   дополнения     
>   *Деревня, где скучал Евгений, Была                                                                                   прелестный
>   уголок.*
>
> **2**            тяготиться чем-н.    творит.
>   падеж         
>   *Нет, он скучает бранной славой.*
>
> **3**            тосковать о ком-н.,
>                 чём-н.                       
>   *по* + предл. п.         
>   *Она очень по тебе скучает.*
>
> **4**            надоедать,
>                 докучать                  
>   дат. падеж              
>   *Нескладно хоть играл, Но Музам
>
>                                                                                      не скучал.*
>
> В современном языке значения 2 и 4 устарели, а потому и управление
>   скучать чем и скучать чему-кому не встречается.
>
> Вот и **причина 1:** изменение управления часто связано с изменением
>   значения слова. Сохранились значения 1 и 3. Значение 1 используется
>   без дополнения, поэтому о синтаксических изменениях говорить не
>   приходится, а вот на значении 3 стоит остановиться. Значение-то
>   осталось, но управление изменилось. И здесь мы сталкиваемся с другими
>   причинами.
>
> **Причина 2:** синтаксическая аналогия, а именно, изменение управления
>   могло произойти под влиянием управления близких по значению глаголов.
>   Под влиянием так называемых глаголов горестного состояния (грустить,
>   тосковать и под.) глагол скучать приобретает управление скучать о чём,
>   которого у него не было раньше.
>
> **Причина 3:** изменение управления глагола могло быть вызвано и
>   изменением управления предлога. Именно с этим связана замена
>   управления скучать по чём-ком на скучать по кому-чему...
>
> (1) Предлог по употребляется с глаголами горестного состояния типа
>   грустить, тосковать, скучать и соответствующими отглагольными
>   существительными. В настоящее время в таких случаях используется
>   дательный падеж: грустить по мужу, скучать по другу, тоска по родному
>   дому. Однако в XIX веке картина была иная. С этими глаголами
>   использовался предлог по и с дательным, и с предложным падежами, но
>   дательный употреблялся лишь с существительными во множественном числе,
>   а предложный — с существительными в единственном числе и с 
>   местоимениями: *Она **вздыхала по другом*** (А. С. Пушкин); *Всё
>   **грустит по муже*** (И. А. Гончаров); ***Что погреба? Признаюсь, и по них сердце болит*** (А. С. Пушкин); *И начинает понемногу Моя Татьяна
>   понимать Теперь яснее — слава богу — Того, **по ком** она **вздыхать**
>   Осуждена судьбою властной* (А. С. Пушкин).
>
> Постепенно дательный вытесняет предложный, уже в 80-е годы XIX века
>   встречаются и употребления существительных в единственном числе в
>   форме дательного падежа, с XX века дательный существительных вытесняет
>   предложный. Примеры с существительными женского рода и личными
>   местоимениями ед. числа 1-го и 2-го лица и женского рода 3-го лица не
>   привожу, они весьма многочисленны, но не показательны, так как в этих
>   случаях формы дательного и предложного падежа омонимичны. Предложный
>   падеж местоимений удерживает свои позиции дольше, до начала ХХ века.
>   Отдельные употребления встречаются вплоть до нашего времени: ***По
>   ком*** это ему **скучать**? — не поднимая глаз, говорит Лина, но полные
>   губы её невольно растягиваются в улыбку. — Может, **по вас**?
>   (Валентина Осеева. 1959); ***Тоскую по нём*** (Виктор Некрасов. 1981);
>   *Этим я хочу сказать, что **скучаю по Вас*** (Борис Ефимов. 2000).
>
> В настоящее время дательный падеж явно преобладает и в последних
>   словарях указывается как единственно правильный вариант.

<sup>источник: [Е. Муравенко *"Об изменениях в синтаксисе
современного русского языка"*, опубл. в *Лингвистика для всех: лет. лингвист. шк. 2005 и 2006, под ред. Е. Муравенко*, стр. 165-7](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=qAX6jcySjYsC&pg=PA165&lpg=PA165&dq#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sup>

> С местоимениями употребляется предложный падеж, а с существительными
>   возможно употребление и предложного и дательного: тосковать по
>   товарищу и по товарище; скучаю по дому и по доме; в литературном языке
>   предпочтительнее употребление дательного падежа

<sup>*И. М Пулькина "Краткий справочник по русской грамматике: пособие для преподавателей нерусских школ" 1961 г.*</sup>

Comment: `Традиционно правильно по вас` — но почему? Заменяем местоимение на существительное (*скучаю по (чему?) коню*), и тут же выяснится, что предложный падеж не удастся натянуть даже при всём желании (скучаю по коне́?)

Comment: @Arhad традиционно с **местоимениями**, но с **существительными**  предложный падеж уместен видимо не со всеми, или даже скорее только с некоторыми... не думаю что можно дать аргументированный ответ на вопрос "почему?" относительно логики падежного управления... так сложилось...

Comment: То есть современный вариант — это унификация через выкидывание какого-то старого правила, забытого, но перешедшего в традицию. Понял, спасибо.

Comment: Так, рассуждение дилетанта. Вот эти 2 формы могли бы различать, единичному ли человеку, предмету речи адресовано высказывание или нет. *по вам* - это явно к группе людей, предметов. Ну, и тогда оставшееся *по вас* пусть будет про единичного собеседника, предмет речи единичного количества. Можно было бы, к примеру, так условиться, ИМХО.

Comment: @Arhad: _скучаю по коне_ was the norm as recently as early XX century

Comment: Arioch,)) Извините, только увидел.

Answer (score -1):

"скучаю по вам"
коротко и ясно... а "по вас" - так в деревне говорят, ну может еще в Эстонии :)

Comment: Сыпасибо) за ответы.

Comment: пожалуйста! а тот кто поставил мне -1, похоже в деревне и живет...